# iOS 8 auto-layout: when can I get the width of a table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a table view, which will be as wide as the screen. The table view contains many custom cells, which will be added programmatically. When displaying these cells, I need to know width of the cells to calculate its height. The problem is, I keep getting wrong values using `cell.frame.width` in:

1. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate func
2. `willDisplayCell` delegate func
3. `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate func

So the question is, when (or where) can I get this value? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Presumably you don't want just to use `tableView.frame.size.width` because you're interested in the width of `cell.contentView`?

Comment: @Tommy Yep, coz `cell.contentView` would be more acurate as more ui elements may be added later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are not changing the `UITableViewCell`'s width the you don't need to get cell width, just take the `UITableView`'s width that will do.

If you want to customize tableview cell frame implement `setFrame` in your custom cell.

As Tommy mentioned "The only issue is that your contentView's width depends on things like the editing state of that cell and any accessory you've added to it (between which the OS will add padding). Ideally you'd be able to interrogate for what content width will be given the editing state, etc, when being asked what the cell height should be. I've never found a means to achieve that directly."

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: The only issue is that your `contentView`'s width depends on things like the editing state of that cell and any avcessory you've added to it (between which the OS will add padding). Ideally you'd be able to interrogate for what content width will be given the editing state, etc, when being asked what the cell height should be. I've never found a means to achieve that directly.

Comment: @Tommy > Yeah, thats right. Thanks for your elaboration. But my point was almost similar, thanks I'll add this part to then answer.

Comment: @Rashad Thank you for the quick response! Currently, the cell takes 100% width of the table, so I suppose I can take that value for now. But I prefer a more dynamic and smart way.

Comment: @fengye87 > As you can see there is no such way. So if you are not editing the table you can rely on tableview's width.

Comment: @Rashad if you're not editing or applying accessory views, that should always be 100% reliable. Otherwise you'll have to mess about with nonsense about recording old widths and, initially, possibly having to load some cells twice, etc. Not nice stuff.